# Does git "dirty" mean files not staged, or not committed? (glossary conflict)

Tags: git

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_dirty
A working tree is said to be "dirty" if it contains modifications which have not been committed to the current branch.

http://www.gitguys.com/topics/glossary/
Dirty working directory
If files have been updated in the working directory after they were updated in the index then the working directory is considered “dirty”. The working directory is clean if all modified files in the working directory have been added to the index.

If I understand correctly, the "index" is also known as the "staging area" and is a place where files will be stored (copied to? symlinked?) when you have changed them, want to commit them, but haven't done a commit yet. (The first glossary says the staging area can also be used for merging. The second glossary says files are moved there by 'git add'.)

So the two glossaries seem to be saying incompatible things. Which is correct? Or is there some way they could both be correct?

Comment: Aside: the index does not contain copies of (or symlinks to, although this is closer) the files-to-be-committed.  In fact, it contains (along with much other stuff) the SHA-1 values of "blobs" already added to the repository (which may or may not be in some other commit(s), e.g., if you `git add` a file that is identical to one already checked-in, it's already in the repo, and the `add` just makes sure the SHA-1 is in the index too).  A later `git write-tree` turns the index into a tree object, also written into the repository (along with any necessary sub-trees).

Answer (score 22):

They're actually both reasonable claims.  I think the "best answer" is that *both* are wrong, although the former (the kernel.org version) is probably closer.

Consider:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/repo && cd /tmp/repo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/repo/.git/
$ echo contents > file
$ git add file
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) e1731a6] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file
```

We now have a repository with one commit containing one file.

```
$ echo second line >> file; git add file; echo contents > file
```

At this point, the index has `file` with *two* lines in it.  But the work-tree version of `file` has just the one line in it, and matches what's in the repository.

Is `file` dirty?  Well, `git status --short` says that it is, twice (two `M`s).  Both `git diff` and `git diff --cached` show changes (so yes, it's "dirty"), but `git diff HEAD` says there's no change, and if we `git add` it *again* and try `git status`:

```
$ git status --short
MM file
$ git diff HEAD
$ git add file
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Let's put that odd change back and do one more thing.  This time let's use the long form of `git status` so that it gives us more information:

```
$ echo second line >> file; git add file; echo contents > file
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   file
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   file
#
```

It says we can use `git reset` (which is the same as `git reset --mixed`) with `HEAD` and the file name to un-stage; surely that will make the working directory dirty? :-)

```
$ git reset HEAD file
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

No, in fact, it makes the working directory clean again!  This follows from the (lack of) output of `git diff HEAD`: "un-staging" the change that adds the second line makes the index refer to the `HEAD` version, and the working-directory version is the same as the `HEAD` version, so un-staging the "changes to be committed" causes there to be nothing to commit *and* no working-directory changes.

The "right" definition is, I think, that your tree is "clean" if there are no changes to commit *and* no changes between "tree staged for commit" (contents of index) and "work directory".  However, it's reasonable to ask separately whether the index is clean (i.e., there is nothing staged for commit) and/or the work-tree is clean (unchanged) with respect to *fill-in-the-blank*, where the blank can be filled in with "the staging area" or "the `HEAD` commit".

What `git status` tells you is both the answer to "what, if anything, is staged for commit" and "what, if anything, is different between the work-tree and the index".  You have to use `git diff HEAD` (you may want to add `--name-only` or similar) to see what, if anything, is different between the work-tree and the `HEAD` commit *unless* (as is often the case) the index matches the `HEAD` commit.

Comment: Another way of stating this, I think, would be to note that a "dirty" status must always have a reference - the answer to "dirty with respect to what?". As you've shown, a working tree file can be "dirty" with respect to the index, or the latest commit, or both. Just stating that a file is "dirty" is ambiguous. Admittedly, the `git` docs could probably be cleaned up somewhat in this respect (and especially the `git`-related unofficial third party stuff, which, if you're not careful, tends to be all over the map as far as quality goes...).

Answer (score 12):

According to the official Git documentation, in the section on [Stashing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing), a dirty state is defined as `... the dirty state of your working directory — that is, your modified tracked files and staged changes`. From this definition, files staged for commit are dirty as well. This means that the `kernel.org` article is correct, while the `gitguys.com` article is pretty much wrong. You should probably point this out to them.

Answer (score 10):

From [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20643773/6309):

> What `git status` tells you is both the answer to:
>
> - "what, if anything, is staged for commit" and
> - "what, if anything, is different between the work-tree and the index".

Note that only the working tree is involved with git status, not the "working directory".

Git 2.9.1+ (Q3 2016) will make that clearer.
See [commit 2a0e6cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2a0e6cdedab306eccbd297c051035c13d0266343) (09 Jun 2016) by [Lars Vogel (`vogella`)](https://github.com/vogella).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a010d61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a010d61e8819205b153afe00744f882e5761b424), 27 Jun 2016)</sup>

> ### Use "working tree" instead of "working directory" for `git status`
>
> **Working directory can be easily confused with the current directory**.
>   In one of my patches I already updated the usage of working directory with working tree for the man page but I noticed that `git status` also uses this incorrect term.